# Смена цвета текста во всем приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

Пользователь с помощью SeekBar выбирает нужный цвет (RGB) для текста. После выбора, этот цвет текста должен быть установлен для **всего** текста в приложении.
Как это сделать программно?

Я понимаю, что можно сделать несколько цветовых тем в stiles.xml и потом их применять. Но вся проблема в том, что мне не нужны предустановленные темы. Мне нужно чтобы цвет выбирал, с помощью "ползунков" сам пользователь.

Ну и еще: прописывать смену цвета теста каждого view в коде вручную, тоже решение не очень...

Comment: На вскидку, более-менее лаконичное решение: сделать наследника `TextView` и везде использовать его. В его конструкторе реализовать установку цвета текста из преференсов и повесить коллбек на изменение этого преференса, в котором устанавливать новый цвет. Соответственно остаётся только записывать в префы цвет после выбора юзером. Хотя есть другие текстовые виджеты (ака `EditText`, `Button`, ...) - тогда с ними придется проделывать тот же фокус.